# Is it possible that start spiders in a loop?

Tags: scrapy

```
while 1:
    url = f.readline()
    if not url:
        break

    _url = 'http://' + url.split()[0]
    _domain = get_domain(_url)
    process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
    process.crawl(mycrwalspider(), su=[_url], ad=[_domain])
    process.start()
```

above is my core code, I want to crawl these urls(too much) in a loop. but when I run, I got a error:

```
twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable
```

I found many articles, but didn't find a suitable method. I have known that reactor only start once, but what I want to do is start the spider in a loop.
what should I do?

I found a solution：

```
for url in urls:
   # url : [['www.a.com'],['www.b.com'],...]
    p1 = Process(target=run_spiders, args=(success_flag, url,))
    p1.start()
    p1.join()
```

so if I have 1000s url to run, I can run 100 urls every time, sum 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

put `process.start()` outside of loop

```
while 1:
    url = f.readline()
    if not url:
        break

    _url = 'http://' + url.split()[0]
    _domain = get_domain(_url)
    process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
    process.crawl(mycrwalspider(), su=[_url], ad=[_domain])
process.start()
```